# How to configure Helm to deploy multiple microservices(payment,order) into different environments(dev,QA) using AKS?

Tags: deployment, ansible, microservices, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm quite new to Helm. I'm learning to automate the microservices deployment using helm and azure kubernetes service. I need to deploy  multiple microservices(payment,order) into different environments(dev,QA).

As per my analysis I hope we achieve this by following steps

1. Create separate clusters for different environments
2. Create multiple variable files based on environments.

we can pass only cluster name and variable file based on our deployment. so it will deploy according to our inputs.

I'm trying to implement the same, but I'm not sure how to configure the above scenarios in helm part in real time.

Shall we achieve this completely using helm alone or shall we use Ansible for orchestration along with helm ?

Anyone could you please advise me on this and suggest me any other best practices if we have?

Reference :

https://codefresh.io/helm-tutorial/helm-deployment-environments/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's currently blocking you? It's unclear from your question what part of the solution are you finding hard to implement.

Comment: @yardon I'm thinking how can we have configure and pass cluster environment name dynamically?  Because azure we will create different subscriptions for different clusters. So I'm not sure how to achieve this part using helm.

Comment: I'm wondering shall we achieve this completely using helm alone or shall we use Ansible for orchestration along with helm ?

Comment: Helm cannot control which cluster it's deploying to, this is being decided by the kubeconfig file on the machine used to invoke the helm command. If your kubeconfig file is configured to access multiple clusters, you can just set the right context before each `helm install` command, and it will target the command at the cluster of your choice.

Comment: I'm posting the latest comment as an answer to this question, since the thread seems to have stopped. @Debugger - if this answers your question please consider accepting it for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Helm cannot control which cluster it's deploying to, this is being decided by the kubeconfig file on the machine used to invoke the helm command.
If your kubeconfig file is configured to access multiple clusters, you can just set the right context before each helm install command, and it will target the command at the cluster of your choice.